# How to receive parameter in aspx page?

Tags: html, asp.net, iframe

I have an .html page that has a link to .aspx page.

I'm sending parameters from html to aspx like that:

```
<a href="javascript:openContent('page1.aspx?id=7&details_id=7', 870, 1050, 200, 300)">Page 1</a>
```

On my .aspx page I have an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://mywebsite.com/?page_id="<%=Request.QueryString["id"]%>"&details_id='<%=Request.QueryString["details_id"]%>' scrolling='no' width="850" height="800" frameborder=0></iframe>
```

And the page I wanted to display is not displayed. I'm not getting an error, but my formatting changed and different frame is displayed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The page I wanted to display is not displayed. I'm not getting an error, but my formatting changed and different frame is displayed. Maybe something wrong how I format a frame source with QueryString?

Comment: Still not clear to me. Where is the problem? Is the javascript called correctly? If not, show us. Maybe you can create a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: I do no have a java script. I just want to pass parameters from html tp aspx and looks like I'm not embedding Request teh right way/

Comment: And where did you get the `openContent` function from?

Comment: it is in my .js file. And is accepting url which I pass. Right now what I need is for this link to work. It would be great if someone will be able to help

Comment: You just said before there was no javascript and now it is. Show us the openContent function. I guess the problem lies in there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `openContent` function does not exist, since you say you have no javascript yourself.

I suggest to change this

```
<a href="javascript:openContent('page1.aspx?id=7&details_id=7', 870, 1050, 200, 300)">Page 1</a>
```

to

```
<a href="javascript:open('page1.aspx?id=7&details_id=7', 870, 1050, 200, 300)">Page 1</a>
```

Comment: openContent is my java script function declared in .js file that opens pop up windows with specified urls

Comment: If you use `open` instead of your own function, does it work then or not? Then you know where to look.

Comment: window is opened either way. Only with openContent I'm able to open a pop up window and resize/locate it the way I want. With open(), the full page is opened with the same content as with openContent method

Comment: In my code this is perfectly valid and works. You use the `QueryString` correctly, so that isn't it. Just thinking of other options: can you call the url separately and check whether the parameters are passed correctly into the code?

Comment: Yes. I passed the URL and it opened the correct page